# How to 301 redirect an old URL to a nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Here is the problem:

When someone types in `domain.com/branches/10`

I need to redirect to `domain.com/businesses/1/branches/10`

New Route

```
  resources :businesses do
    resources :branches
  end
```

Old Route

```
  match 'branches/:id', to: 'branches#show'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out:

```
match '/branches(/*path)' => redirect{ |params| "/businesses/#{Branch.find(params[:path]).business.to_param}/branches/#{Branch.find(params[:path]).to_param}" }
```

I also needed to add the `.to_param` as I recently also switched to semi friendly urls (id+name). This works for converting either an id or a friendly url to the new nested path.